# Creating string text with if-else in linq

Tags: c#, linq, if-statement

I want to get the result of more than one if else query in a single string in linq, I can get the result I want thanks to the method I wrote earlier, but I want to include it in my linq query.

I keep data from 4 columns in a row. I can operate with one line of this, but I want to receive data from 4 lines next to each other

Linq code:

```
select new{
   Ists = kart.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == sk.id) != 8
      ? kart.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == sk.id).ist1
      : ""
};
```

Example input:

```
ist1=ISTANBUL, ist2=KONYA, ist3=ANKARA, ist4=IZMIR
```

Output i want:

```
Ists= ISTANBUL + KONYA + ANKARA + IZMIR
```

Comment: Have you looked at `.Take` of `Linq`? If I understand you correctly, you want to take 4 records at a time from your list?

Comment: It's unclear to me what you're trying to achieve, given that in your condition `FirstOrDefault` appears to return an integer, and then you're trying to dereference it. A [mcve] would make it *much* easier to help you - along with details of what your data source is. (In-memory? SQL using EF Core? Something else?)

Comment: thanks for answer,
There are 4 columns in 1 row in the list. I want to get the data in 4 columns in each row side by side.

Comment: Again, a [mcve] would make it much easier to help you. (It's not clear to me what you mean by "side by side", or what the data types involved are, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did custom method for all possibility.

```
string Find(int hammaddeId)
        {
            var str = "";
            var hammadde = hammaddeler.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == hammaddeId);
            if (hammadde.istasyon1 != 8)
            {
                str += "- " + istasyonlar.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == hammadde.istasyon1).istasyonadi;
            }
            if (hammadde.istasyon2 != 8)
            {
                str += "- " + istasyonlar.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == hammadde.istasyon2).istasyonadi;
            }
            if (hammadde.istasyon3 != 8)
            {
                str += "- " + istasyonlar.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == hammadde.istasyon3).istasyonadi;
            }
            if (hammadde.istasyon4 != 8)
            {
                str += "- " + istasyonlar.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == hammadde.istasyon4).istasyonadi;
            }
            return str;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your *example provided*, may be try using *regular expressions* instead of *Linq* in order to `Match` all the parts?

```
  using System.Linq; // <- To query Regex.Matches
  using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

  ...

  string data = @"ist1=ISTANBUL, ist2=KONYA, ist3=ANKARA, ist4=IZMIR";

  // To obtain "ists" I've used "^[A-Za-z]+" pattern
  // If "ists" is constant you can drop it and put 
  // string result = "ists= " + string.Join(...  
  string result = $"{Regex.Match(data, "^[A-Za-z]+")}s= " + string.Join(" + ", Regex
    .Matches(data, @"(?<=\=\s*)\p{L}+")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(match => match.Value));

  Console.Write(result);
```

Outcome:

```
  ists= ISTANBUL + KONYA + ANKARA + IZMIR
```